# How to get the text appearing in class element

Tags: java, selenium

`<span class="LogoTitle">Management Console</span>`

I'm trying to verify if the "Management Console" text is present or not
, I can't find the locator from the above code

Comment: Your code trials as in `can't find the locator`?

Comment: I mean i don't know how to write the locator for the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to extract the text **Management Console** you can use the following *Locator Strategy*:

- *XPath*:

  ```
  String myText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='LogoTitle']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```

**Note**: Ensure that the *class* attribute `LogoTitle` uniquely identifies the element. Else you have to traverse up the DOM and refer the parent tag/node.

Comment: That worked, used string to get the text  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
        You can get this by using Xpath, try using follwing- 

        **Locating Strategy**

        //span[contains(@class, 'LogoTitle') and normalize-space(text()) = 'Management Console']

        **To Verify Text Present**

        //span[contains(@class, 'LogoTitle') and normalize-space(text()) = 'Management Console'].isDisplayed();

        or 

        Write a function which does this for you, if you're using **Page Object Model**


        @FindBy(xpath="//span[contains(@class, 'LogoTitle') and normalize-space(text()) = 'Management Console']")
        WebElement textManagementConsole;

        Public boolean isManagementConsoleTextPresent(){
         textManagementConsole.isDisplayed();
        }


    Public void isManagementConsoleTextPresentTest(){
    Assert.assertTrue(isManagementConsoleTextPresent(), "Management Console Text Not Present");
}
```